# create time stamps tuple python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to create a tuple of time stamps.
Where If I define a function like

```
def time_stamps(starttime,endtime,intervals):
    #start time of tuple like 08:00:00
    #End time of tuple like 21:00:00
    #With Intervals of 60 or 30 0r 90 minutes.
    #example  : if i call the function 
    #x = time_stamps(08:00:00,21:00:00,00:30:00)
    #It should generate a tuple like this
    #('08:00:00','08:30:00','09:00:00',....,'20:30:00','21:00:00)
```

I am lost.Please Help.
Thank you

Comment: You probably at least tried something?

Comment: Furthermore what if the `endtime` is before the `starttime`, like `time_stamps('1:00:00', '0:00:00', '0:01:00')`?

Comment: if the end time is before starttime, i guess we need to raise an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dateutils's parser` to parse the time in string format to `datetime` object. We can then easily compute the count based on time delta, with which we can generate a tuple

```
from dateutil import parser
def time_stamps(starttime,endtime,intervals):
    start = parser.parse(starttime)
    end   = parser.parse(endtime)
    intervals = parser.parse(intervals) - parser.parse('00:00:00')
    count = int((end-start)/intervals)
    return tuple(( str((start+i*intervals).time()) for i in range(count+1)))

>>> time_stamps('10:00:00', '12:00:00', '00:30:00')
('10:00:00', '10:30:00', '11:00:00', '11:30:00', '12:00:00')
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of dateutil model until now. It worked!! Thank you so much